# ImageMagick format conversion issue

Tags: imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to convert an rgba8888 png to rgba5551, rgb565, and rgba4444 PNGs.

Regarding the conversion to rgba5551, I'm getting a grey-scale image instead of a colour image with the following command:

```
convert  -depth 8 "$1" \
        -channel R +level 0,31 -evaluate multiply 2048 +channel \
        -channel G +level 0,31 -evaluate multiply 64 +channel \
        -channel B +level 0,31 -evaluate multiply 2 +channel \
        -channel A +level 0,1 +channel \
        -channel RGBA -separate +channel \
        -channel R -evaluate-sequence add  +channel \
        -depth 16  "$2"
```

Could someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: This reference says it is packing the data into one channel. So a 16-bit grayscale image. See https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=19752#p77910

Comment: I see... so this only works on png -> raw formats

Comment: No, it can work on any input format. The issue is that the code you are using makes only a single grayscale 16-bit result. Any format that supports 16-bit grayscale is acceptable for the output.